# How to include a search box on an IIS webserver so that a file residing on the server can be found?

Tags: file, iis, search, webserver

I just setup an IIS 7.5 webserver on Windows 2008 R2 server whose inetpub/wwwroot folder acts as a file (jpg, wav, pdf etc) repository for LAN users who can search for a particular file on the server. inetpub/wwwroot folder doesn't have even a single html file or any other webpage. All it has is thousands of jpg, wav, pdf, xlsx, docx files in hundreds of folders.
I have enabled directory listing on the server so a user can browse through all the files but I want a search box where a user can enter partial or full file name to search for a given file.

All I have tried is to find a solution on the web for seemingly a simple problem but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is impossible to achieve this with native IIS feature. You may need to hard code this function into a .net application or a HTML/javascript page with URL rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In that case, I will try to find some code that can achieve this functionality.